# Replace all words in a String that are in an array with words in the same position of another array

Tags: java

In java, what would be the easiest way to replace all words in a string that are in an array with words from another array?

For example, if I had the arrays

`["a", "b", "c"]` and `["x", "y", "z"]`

how would I take the string `"a b c d e"` and turn it into `"x y z d e"`?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to find the positions of the words you would like to replace and hence integrate the new values in those positions:

```
String[] oldArray = {"a", "b", "c"};
String[] newArray = {"x", "y", "z"};

String text = "a b c d e";
int count = 0;

System.out.println("Text before: " + text);

for (String element : oldArray) {
    if (text.contains(element)) {
        text = text.substring(0, text.indexOf(element)) + newArray[count] + text.substring(text.indexOf(element) + 1, text.length());
    }
    count++;
}

System.out.println("Text after: " + text);
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps using a *HashMap* as such:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("a", "x");
map.put("b", "y");
map.put("c", "z");

String string = "a b c d e";

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()){
     while (string.contains(entry.getKey())){
          string = string.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the most straightforward way

```
String[] s1 = {"a", "b", "c"};
String[] s2 = {"x", "y", "z"};

String abc = "a b c d e";

for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
    abc = abc.replaceAll(s1[i], s2[i]);
}

System.out.println(abc);
```

Output:

```
x y z d e
```